# Angular - access component variable from ng-content

Tags: angular

how to access component variables from component content without use #id ?

for example this is a component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class ListComponent  {
  constructor() { }
  @Input() name: string; 
  time = 12;  
  }
```

and I use it in AppComponent like this :

```
<app-list #list1 name="vlad">
 time is : {{list1.time}}
</app-list>
```

it works but every time I need a variable , must use list.[variablename]

how access variables without use #id ?
something like self.time or this.time ??

Comment: …hmm.. I don’t think you need list1..? Just {{time}} should work.. right..? Doubting myself now 

Comment: I think you should have a look at @ContentChild